# how to pass data from ajax to controller then reload to view page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, codeigniter

i use code igniter, i dont know if its duplicate because i've search almost all based on my title.

just like my tittle i'd like to pass data from ajax, process it in controller then show it in view.

here my jquery

```
$('.input').click(function(){
        var id_ticket = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : '<?=site_url("settlement/edit_trouble_ticket");?>',
            data : 'id='+id_ticket,
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#ajax-loader').show();
            },
            error: function(){
                $('#ajax-loader').hide();
                alert('Error\nGagal request data');
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#ajax-loader').hide();
                //??
            }
        });
    });
```

after pass those data here the process in my controller

```
function edit_trouble_ticket() {
        $where = trim($this->input->post('id'));

        $out = $this->settlement_model->get_trouble_tiket($where);
        foreach ($out as $row) {
                $result['id']               = $row->id;
                $result['mid']              = $row->mid;
        }
        $this->load->view('rekon_settlement/cm_edit', $result);
    }
```

the model is just some code to get all those data, after i got those result i'd like to see the result in my view
here my simple chunk of my view:

```
<table class="formstable">
                    <tr><th colspan="2">Data Trouble Ticket</th></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>MID</td>
                        <td><?=form_input('', $result['mid'], 'disabled="disabled"')?><?=form_hidden('mid', $result['mid'])?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>TID</td><td><?=form_input('', $result['tid'], 'disabled="disabled"')?><?=form_hidden('tid', $result['tid'])?></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <?=form_reset('reset', 'Reset', 'class="button reset"')?>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <?=form_submit('submit', 'Submit', 'class="button submit" onclick="return confirm(\'Apa Anda yakin?\');"')?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: What is your problem? Error?

Comment: To reload your page after the process, you can imagine your controller method displaying some JSON. Your ajax can parse the json result and reload if it's done, show an error if it's not, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You will have to redirect using js depending on result returned from the call

```
$('.input').click(function(){
    var id_ticket = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : '<?php echo site_url("settlement/edit_trouble_ticket");?>',
       // make sure your providing proper url t
        data : {id:id_ticket},
        beforeSend:function(){
            $('#ajax-loader').show();
        },
        error: function(){
            $('#ajax-loader').hide();
            alert('Error\nGagal request data');
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#ajax-loader').hide();
            if(data['res']){
                window.location.assign("https://www.yoursite.com");
             }         
        }
    });
});
//ajax edit


function edit_trouble_ticket() {
$result=array();
$result['res']=false;
    $where = trim($this->input->post('id'));
    $out = $this->settlement_model->get_trouble_tiket($where);

    foreach ($out as $row) {
            $result['id']               = $row->id;
            $result['mid']              = $row->mid;
    }

    // Am not sure hat the model returns if no match.so i will do
    if(count($result)>0){
        $result['res']=true;
    }

    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($result));

}
```

Comment: where do i asign the view

Comment: from the success in  the ajax call  success: function(data){
            $('#ajax-loader').hide();
            if(data['res']){
                window.location.assign("https://www.yoursite.com");
             }         
        }

Comment: blank page, the page has no response

Answer (score 0):

I just read your title, and i think you can use javascript function `window.location` to reload whole your view page after ajax send

Comment: if i do the reload it reaload the page i open now

Answer (score 0):

I use code igniter a lot

When you get the response from ajax use .html
Link
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp

Eg
      $("p").html("Hello **world**!");

No need to reload your page

Comment: i need to pass the data from the controller

Answer (score 0):

Change the `id` ajax parameter and then apply any jquery method you'd like to display the returned view, such as using `append()` method :

```
$('.input').click(function(){
    var id_ticket = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : '<?=site_url("settlement/edit_trouble_ticket");?>',
        data : {id:id_ticket},
        beforeSend:function(){
            $('#ajax-loader').show();
        },
        error: function(){
            $('#ajax-loader').hide();
            alert('Error\nGagal request data');
        },
        success: function(html){
            // $('#ajax-loader').hide();
            $('#ajax-loader').parent().append(html);
        }
    });
});
```

And set a `TRUE` on third parameter so that it returns data as a string rather than sending it to your browser :

```
$cm_edit = $this->load->view('rekon_settlement/cm_edit', $result, TRUE);
echo $cm_edit;
```